# mysqld got signal 11

Tags: mariadb, galera

I have MariaDB in Galera cluster of 3 nodes. Periodically, each node in the cluster restarts by sending yourself a signal 11. I scoured the Internet in search of a solution to the problem, but to no avail. The only thing that could be similar to my problem, it - https://serverfault.com/questions/678128/percona-cluster-signal-11. But I have not found confirmation of this.
I duplicated the problem to the developers MariaDB, but they are in no hurry to solve it: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-14584

**error.log**:

```
2017-12-05  9:27:13 140599126464256 [Note] WSREP: (8f3cb7d9, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') turning message relay requesting off
171205 11:38:01 [ERROR] mysqld got signal 11 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.

To report this bug, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs

We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

Server version: 10.2.10-MariaDB-log
key_buffer_size=16777216
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=15
max_threads=102
thread_count=23
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 240475 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x7fddf40009a8
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
```

**server.cnf**:

```
# this is read by the standalone daemon and embedded servers
[server]

# this is only for the mysqld standalone daemon
[mysqld]
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
transaction-isolation = READ-COMMITTED
max_allowed_packet = 16M
myisam_recover_options = BACKUP
max_connections = 100
sql_mode =

# Logs
log_error = /var/lib/mysql/logs/mysql_error.log
slow_query_log = 1
slow_query_log_file = /var/lib/mysql/logs/mysql_slow.log
long_query_time = 2


# Cache parameters
query_cache_size = 64M
query_cache_limit = 2M
table_open_cache = 4096
thread_cache_size = 200
key_buffer_size = 16M
thread_stack = 128K
join_buffer_size = 2M
sort_buffer_size = 2M

# Parameters for temporary tables
tmpdir = /tmp
max_heap_table_size = 512M
tmp_table_size = 512M
query_cache_type=1

# InnoDB parameters
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 4G
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_log_file_size = 128M
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT

# Database charset parameters
character-set-server = utf8
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect = "SET NAMES utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci"
skip-character-set-client-handshake
#skip-name-resolve

#
# * Galera-related settings
#
[galera]
# Mandatory settings
wsrep_on = ON
wsrep_provider = /usr/lib64/galera/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_cluster_address = "gcomm://192.168.59.78,172.16.140.29"
wsrep_cluster_name = "site-appdb"
wsrep_node_address = "192.168.59.78"
wsrep_node_name = "site-appdb01"
wsrep_sst_method = rsync
wsrep_sst_auth=repl_user:+vQvI9Fe8Nr6
binlog_format = row
default_storage_engine = InnoDB
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 2
#innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog = 1
#
# Allow server to accept connections on all interfaces.
#
#bind-address=0.0.0.0
#
# Optional setting
wsrep_slave_threads=1
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 4G
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_log_file_size = 128M
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT

# this is only for embedded server
[embedded]

# This group is only read by MariaDB servers, not by MySQL.
# If you use the same .cnf file for MySQL and MariaDB,
# you can put MariaDB-only options here
[mariadb]

# This group is only read by MariaDB-10.1 servers.
# If you use the same .cnf file for MariaDB of different versions,
# use this group for options that older servers don't understand
[mariadb-10.1]
```

Comment: A shot in the dark, but: `transaction-isolation = READ-COMMITTED` and `binlog_format = row`: According to the [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/set-transaction/): "REPEATABLE READ [...] This is the only transaction level that can be used with the row based binary logging."

Comment: Are you doing anything unusual at the time of the crashes? Also, are you aware of the [limitations of Galera](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mariadb-galera-cluster-known-limitations/)? Not adhering to some of these will result in crashes. E.g. having a table without explicit primary keys and then deleting from that table.

Comment: Possibly unrelated, but how much RAM do you have?  I assume at least 8G?  These should be no more than, say, 80M:  `max_heap_table_size`, `tmp_table_size`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to say anything for certain, but one thing I noticed is that you're also using an old version of the galera RPM (25.3.12). Version 25.3.20 is the one distributed with the version of MariaDB you're using (10.2.10).

Comment: There is another Galera cluster on which the problem occurs and it have Galera last version:

`# rpm -qa | grep galera

galera-25.3.20-1.rhel7.el7.centos.x86_64`

Comment: @Валерий Казанцев You should still upgrade. What about jemalloc, which version do you have of that?